# PHP - MySQL I always got username exists, but why?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I tried `echo($numrows);`

`numrows` is equal to `0`.
then why i got this error : **username exists?**

I went trough it all many times, but I can't find what is the problem..

```
<?php

function generateRandomString($length = 6) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

//innen regiszt:
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$email1 = strip_tags($_POST['email1']);
$email2 = strip_tags($_POST['email2']);
$pw1 = strip_tags($_POST['pw1']);
$pw2 = strip_tags($_POST['pw2']);

if($username&&$email1&&$email2&&$pw1&&$pw2)
    {
     if ($email1==$email2)
         {
             if ($pw1==$pw2)
             {               
                 if (5<strlen($pw1)&&20>=strlen($pw1))
                 {
                    if (5<strlen($pw1)&&20>=strlen($pw1)) 
                    {                       
                    $connect = mysql_connect('HOST','UNAME','PW');
                    $database = mysql_select_db('virtualtc',$connect);  
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
                    $querymail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email1'");
                    $numrowsmail = mysql_num_rows($querymail);
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                       if ($numrows=0)
                       {
                            if ($querymail=0)  
                            {
                                $md5pass= md5($pw1);
                                $date=date("Y-m-d");
                                $query3 = mysql_query(
                                    "INSERT INTO users VALUES '','$username','$md5pass','$email1', 0 ,'$date'");
                                include("registration_complete.php");//regist

                            }else include("/errors/email_exists.html");//email exists
                       }else include("/errors/user_exists.html")//user exists                   
                    }else include("/errors/uname_length.html");//username length 6-20!                   
                 }else include("/errors/pass_length.html"); //password length 6-20!              
             } else include("/errors/different_pw.html");//different password
         } else include("/errors/different_email.html");//different email
    } else include("/errors/empty_regist.html");//empty field


?>
```

Comment: if ($numrows=0) should be if ($numrows==0) -- you are setting $numrows to 0 which will always be true, instead of testing if it is 0.

Comment: @DragonYen Small typo in your comment `if($numrows = 0)` will always be false.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: @ all answers given below (so far).- You missed so many syntax errors, it's not funny. *Ain't it Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Nope, Ralph.* Points should be awarded for completeness @Fred-ii-

Comment: *I agree totally with you Sam* - @JayBlanchard how many times we get shot down for answers like that. Just because we're higher repped, doesn't mean that lower reps shouldn't be treated the same way. *"What's good for the goose, is good enough for the gander"*, as the saying goes ;-)

Comment: *We're being ignored Sam* - @JayBlanchard and an answer accepted? lol

Comment: *They'll be back Ralph. They always come back.* heh @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Jim - eep, thanks. I can't edit it (been too long I suppose). I could delete it, but then your comment would be out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only one `=` will set `$numrows` to `0`, not checking if `$numrows` IS `0`

```
if($numrows == 0)
```

Comment: how does this answer the question? you've missed quite a bit here.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `if($numrows=0)` which will change `$numrows` to 0 and then check the value. 0 in php equals false so thats why the else block is executed.

**Sidenote:** 
Please for the love of readability, stop writing [arrow code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern). You could write a function to check if a username is taken or not...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning, not comparing

```
if ($numrows=0)
```

should be

```
if ($numrows==0)
```

Same applies to other condition statements.

Well, I don't see your schema, but I would do:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,'$username','$md5pass','$email1', 0 ,'$date')");
```

assuming you first column is AI.

Also, don't forget to prepare your data before you pass it database, for example with addslashes at least.

Comment: True, there's more than one as you mention. If you want to answer this one fully, take a look at what's inside `$query3 = mysql_query(...` ;-) nobody caught that major syntax error.

Comment: Well, I don't see your schema, but I would do:

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,'$username','$md5pass','$email1', 0 ,'$date')")`

Assuming you first column is AI. Also, don't forget to prepare your data before you pass it database, for example with `addslashes` at least.

Comment: I am not the OP here. Look at the names ;-)

Comment: you should also place that in your answer and not in comments, should someone flag that comment containing code and it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($numrows=0)
```

to

```
 if ($numrows==0)
```

`=` means assignment

and

`==` means comparison

For reference [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)